# Load FreeMarker Template for sending email

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-mail, freemarker

I am new to FreeMarker, and i want to use it to send e-mails. My application has integration of Spring 3.1, Hibernate 3.0 and Struts 2 frameworks.

So, basically my code for sending mail is (i'm using java mail api):

```
Message message = new MimeMessage(session);

message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(fromAddress));

Address[] addresses = new Address[1];
addresses[0] = new InternetAddress(fromAddress);
message.setReplyTo(addresses);

message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(toAddress));
message.setSubject(subject);

//To set template using freemarker

 BodyPart bodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();

 Configuration cfg = new Configuration();
 Template template = cfg.getTemplate("template.ftl");
 Map<String, String> rootMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
 rootMap.put("toName", toName);
 rootMap.put("message", sendMessage);
 Writer out = new StringWriter();
 template.process(rootMap, out);

 bodyPart.setContent(out.toString(), "text/html");

 Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
 multipart.addBodyPart(bodyPart);

 message.setContent(multipart,"text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1");

 Transport.send(message);
```

But when it tries to send mail,it throws an Exception :

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: Template "template.ftl" not found.
```

The `template.ftl` file is in `WEB-INF/ftl/` directory.

In my spring-config.xml file, i have added this :

```
<bean id="freemarkerConfig" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerConfigurer">
    <property name="templateLoaderPath" value="/WEB-INF/ftl/"/>
</bean>

<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerViewResolver">
    <property name="cache" value="true"/>
    <property name="prefix" value=""/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".ftl"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: can you try to remove the ftl extension when you call getTemplate?

Comment: Same Exception, Template "template" not found.

Comment: when you try to get the template, you should use the configuration that you've defined in the application context, not create a new one

Comment: As Sergi said, the FreeMarker `Configuration` that you set up under Spring has nothing to do with the FreeMarker Configuration you create in the Java code. In the last you haven't even set up the `TemplateLoader`. (Also if you re-create the `Configuration` for every single mail, it can be quite slow, if you send out a *lot* of mails. A `Configuration` instance meant to be singleton.)

Comment: @SergiAlmar & @ddekany i did that, and its working now. Thanks for your help. :)
But, its taking too much time, is it normal? (I have injected the object of `FreeMarkerConfigurer` to my Email class, and using its `getConfiguration` method to get the object of `Configuration`, and then same as above.)

Answer (score 1):

Add this statement

```
cfg.setClassForTemplateLoading(TestTemplate.class, "templates");
```

before your line

```
Template template = cfg.getTemplate("template.ftl");
```

Add the template path in the same folder of the method that you will refer to "TestTemplate" for example.

Answer (score 0):

You can add setTemplateLoaderPath

```
@Bean
    public FreeMarkerConfigurer freemarkerConfig() throws IOException, TemplateException {
        FreeMarkerConfigurationFactory factory = new FreeMarkerConfigurationFactory();
        factory.setTemplateLoaderPath("classpath:templates");
        factory.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
        FreeMarkerConfigurer result = new FreeMarkerConfigurer();
        result.setConfiguration(factory.createConfiguration());
        return result;
    }


 final Template template = configuration.getTemplate("file.ftl");
        Map root = new HashMap();
        root.put("user", "Big Joe");
        Writer out = new OutputStreamWriter(System.out);
        template.process(root,out);
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that your ftl files are stored under `WEB-INF/freemarker`, so your spring configuration for `freemarkerConfig` will be like this:

```
<bean id="freemarkerConfig" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerConfigurer">
    <property name="templateLoaderPath" value="/WEB-INF/freemarker/" />
</bean>
```

In you controller, inject the `freemarkerConfig` like this:

```
@Resource(name = "freemarkerConfig")
private FreeMarkerConfigurer freemarkerConfig;
```

And load your ftl page like this:

```
Map<String, Object> yourMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
yourMap.put("var1", "");
yourMap.put("var2", "");
......

String content = FreeMarkerTemplateUtils.processTemplateIntoString(freemarkerConfig.getConfiguration().getTemplate("template.ftl"), yourMap );
```

The `content` variable will contain now all your ftl content based on the yourMap  `Map` passed to ftl page, so you can pass it to your api mail.

Check [Class FreeMarkerTemplateUtils Documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/ui/freemarker/FreeMarkerTemplateUtils.html) for more info about `FreeMarkerTemplateUtils.processTemplateIntoString`