# Spring FreeMarker Email

Tags: spring-mvc, freemarker

I am having difficulty getting my SpringMVC project to use FreeMarker.  I found [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18773307/load-freemarker-template-for-sending-email) that was similar, but couldn't piece together the actual solution.  I have a "welcomeEmail.ftl" that I tried putting in both resources/templates and src/templates, but everytime I try and run it I get the error:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: Template "welcomeEmail" not found.
    at freemarker.template.Configuration.getTemplate(Configuration.java:742)
    at freemarker.template.Configuration.getTemplate(Configuration.java:665)
    at com.xxx.utility.mail.FreemarkerFileTransformer.runTransformation(FreemarkerFileTransformer.java:44)
```

Here is my JavaConfig:

```
 @Bean
    public FreeMarkerConfigurer freemarkerConfig() {
        FreeMarkerConfigurer freeMarkerConfigurer = new FreeMarkerConfigurer();
        freeMarkerConfigurer.setTemplateLoaderPath( "/templates" );
        return freeMarkerConfigurer;
    }


    @Bean
    public FreeMarkerViewResolver viewResolver() {
        FreeMarkerViewResolver freeMarkerViewResolver = new FreeMarkerViewResolver();
        freeMarkerViewResolver.setSuffix( ".ftl" );
        freeMarkerViewResolver.setPrefix( "" );
        freeMarkerViewResolver.setCache( true );
        return freeMarkerViewResolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public freemarker.template.Configuration configuration() {
        freemarker.template.Configuration configuration = new freemarker.template.Configuration();
        return configuration;
    }
```

And I try to use FreeMarker as such:

```
...  
private MailSender mailSender;
@Autowired
private FreemarkerFileTransformer freemarkerFileTransformer;


public void sendNewCustomerEmail(OfficeSetup officeSetup) throws Exception  {

    Map<String, String> m = new HashMap<String, String>();
    m.put("ownerName", officeSetup.getFirstName() + " " + officeSetup.getLastName());
    m.put("url", "weburl/" + officeSetup.getOfficeUrl());

    String mailContent = freemarkerFileTransformer.runTransformation(m, "", "welcomeEmail");

    SimpleMailMessage message = new SimpleMailMessage();

    message.setFrom("info@edelweissco.com");
    message.setTo(officeSetup.getUserName());
    message.setSubject("Welcome to eDentalManger, here are your activation details!");
    message.setText(mailContent);
    mailSender.send(message);

}


@Component
public class FreemarkerFileTransformer {

    @Autowired
    private FreeMarkerConfigurer freeMarkerConfigurer;

    @Autowired
    private Configuration configuration;

    public String runTransformation(Map<?, ?> sourceData, String ftlTemplate) throws Exception {

        Template template = configuration.getTemplate( ftlTemplate  );
        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
        template.process(sourceData, writer);
        writer.flush();
        String output = writer.getBuffer().toString();
        return output;
    }
```

Since I am only using FreeMarker for emails, and I don't have a WEB-INF directory, I am not sure where the template files are supposed to be saved to.

Comment: Have you tried creating a `templates` Java package and just put it there? I guess `/templates` will be interpreted as a class-path resource path. Although `classpath:/templates` is nicer then, because it's more obvious.

Comment: Yes, I have both src/main/java/templates and src/test/java/templates.  I also tried putting the file in src/resources and test/resources